# How to support file upload in web-form Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I need a simple extension for Liferay web form to enahance file attachment to data flled in a liferay 7 web form.

Also need to sent this file as an attachment with the email to the registered user.

I know how to achieve this functionality in liferay 6.2 but not about liferay 7. I am using liferay 7 GA-5 CE.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the web form portlet or just in portlets in general?

Comment: web-form portlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom form field type plugin, please find liferay wiki here [Creating Form Field Type](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-form-field-types). and follow below steps,

1. Change input type to file in soy file path is

   > src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/your-plugin-type-name.soy
2. Create a fragment of dynamic.data.list.form.web bundle and override display/view.jsp to accept the file i.e. multipart data.
3. Override **AddRecordMVCActionCommand** action command to store the selected file as you required.
4. Build and deploy all 3 plugins

Hope this will help you.